# Using “you got it” in the sense of “you are welcome”

Tags: idioms, expressions, american-english, formality

Normally I would assume the meaning of *you got it* were something like:

> You do understand it right.
>       You’ve achieved your goal.

Or even

> I’ll do it for you very shortly.

But from time to time I hear it used as a replacement for *you are welcome*, especially in bars, restaurants, or cafés.

Is this just a more polite way of saying the same thing,  or is it more related to informal speech?

Comment: When people in service trades (barmen, waiters, etc.) say it, they mean *"consider it done"* (i.e. - *"I've heard what you want me to do, and you can be confident I'll do it shortly"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It’s like a sailor saying, [“Aye aye, sir!”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aye_aye,_sir)

Comment: Question lacks context. Do you mean you hear people say it in response to "thank you", or what?

Comment: Yes, and when I am already closed bill and ready to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulting the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), one finds it four times in transcripts of unscripted television interviews. A guest says to Sanjay Gupta "Thanks," and Gupta responds (twice) "You got it." Once for Peter Greenberg and once for Dave Karger.
These are journalists and not service workers, so I think it would be fair to say that the phrase has established itself as an informal way of saying "you're welcome."

Here's a full example with context from an interview of Tiger Woods by Jimmy Fallon.

> Fallon: “I want to say thank you for having the courage to come on a late
> night comedy program…. It must have been a painful and awful
> situation, the whole thing you went through, but from a comedian’s
> standpoint, and my monologue writers’, thank you so much. That was
> some of the greatest comedy we did ever. I mean, you must have heard
> every golf joke in history, but that is like a magical thing to
> happen, your awful pain. And we laughed at your pain, and I mean, not
> even making jokes — it kinda wrote itself. I mean, ‘balls,’ ‘shaft,’
> ‘holes,’ ‘foursomes.’ I mean, it really writes itself. I just want to
> say, thank you. thank you, thank you.”
>
> Woods: “You got it.”

Comment: In the "you're welcome" context, it seems to me that it is closely related to "Glad to help, Any time." The full imaginary expression is probably like this: "Any time you need me to do what I just did for you, you got it." This is regardless of the fact that the person saying it probably does not really mean it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with @FumbleFingers. I think it is used in the sense of: *I will give you what you requested*.
I'm afraid I don't know if it's another expression for *You're welcome*.

Comment: It's another pragmatic variant of the same conversational response, tailored to a different pragmatic context. Perfectly normal; language is nothing if not adaptive.

Comment: Agreed, it was the same I thought too. But one thing makes me doubt. Consider example: you took couple bears, paid for them and even done. So you left tips and saying thank you, and in return he says - you got it man

Comment: @dmi3y: As John says, for some speakers it's become a conventional "conversational response" that can't really be analysed that precisely. Consider it equivalent to, say, *"Alright, man!"* - just a general-purpose affirmative/agreeable response to whatever came before.